# OpenID Connect scope/role discovery

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I recently learned how OIDC provides user identity on top of OAuth 2, and also managed to create an OIDC login to my webapp. However, when it comes to the authorization part, it is unclear how the application should know what scopes to request for the API?

For example, certain endpoints should be protected with the 'admin' scope, as well as respective UI elements should be hidden from non-admin users. The enforcement part I can implement easily, but when the user logs in, the app needs to know if the user is an admin or not - i.e whether or not to request the 'admin' scope / show the admin-related UI parts.

Is there any standard way of representing app-specific details in the user profile that comes from the IDP? What disturbs me most is that such information - to my knowledge - cannot be added to user profiles that come from e.g Google/Twitter/Facebook, so one needs either a) an extra layer (IdentityServer/OpenAM/etc), or b) extra user profile data in the webapp's DB.

My first thought was to add custom claims by doing a) - but when it comes to integrating with existing IDPs, it might not be possible to adjust all the user profiles (e.g large corporate databases), so I am assuming the app itself should be flexible enough to translate existing user profile data to 'admin/not-admin'.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: That's not really how it works. If your app needs the `admin` scope, you just ask for it, always. You don't conditionally change your scopes based on who logs in.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not a good practice to base your authorization on the claims returned by your identity providers.
This responsibility should be delegated to the UMA server. It's up to him to decide or not to grant a request access to a protected resource.
For example, image that we have the following scenario :

**Context** : An e-commerce enterprise has internally developed a tool used by his marketing team, to retrieve information about his most loyal clients.
The application has been developed in WPF and interact with a RESTFUL API to retrieve the clients. 
Only this application and users that belong to the marketing group are authorized to retrieve the list.

Problem : How the application can access to the protected operation ?

[image]

[workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfxMX.png)

**Solution** : the workflow is made of three big steps :

- *Identity token* : retrieve an identity token with implicit grant-type. The token is returned to the client in a callback parameter
- *RPT token* : the identity and access token (valid for the scopes uma_authorization & uma_protection) are passed in the request to retrieve the RPT one.
  When it is received by the WPF application, the token is passed in the Authorization header to retrieve the loyal clients. Both parameters are required by the authorization policy.
- *Check RPT token* : the token is checked against the introspection endpoint, this endpoint is offered by the UMA server.

As you can see internal policies are used by the UMA server to grant / or not access to the resource. 
Authorization policy is out of scope of the UMA specification, you have to define it yourself :'(.
I have developed a product (open-source) to easily manage authorization policies. If you are interested you can test the demo here  : 
http://lokit.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/Demo

*Note : If you are not satisfied about claims returned by external identity providers, you can always enrich them (read the use case : "assign role to resource owner" in the documentation)*

Comment: A few points. 1- What does UMA stand for here? 2 - The "Check RPT token" step is not present in your diagram. When does that happen and how does it work? 3 - You are suggesting the use of `implicit grant type` for obtaining the initial token. AFAIK, this grant type is considered dangerous and is not being recommended by OAuth2 providers. They instead recommend using the `authorization` flow or the PKCE flow.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

To control the user profiles and scopes available you will need to control the Identity Provider.

**Approach 1**

- Request all scopes including ‘admin’ scope

  - If token not returned
- Request only default scopes
- Display UI elements accordingly

**Approach 2**

- Only request default scopes
- Request ‘admin’ scope later

  - If token returned
- Update UI

A good resource to check out is the [OAuth 2.0 Simplified](https://www.oauth.com/#mobile-menu) eBook from Okta

### The long explanation

I’ve often run into the same issue when working with developers on integrating OAuth into their apps. I work a lot with Okta and the best recommendation I’ve had given to me by IDP engineers is to make multiple requests for scopes and adjust based on which requests receive a response.

This of course requires that the IDP you are requesting the token from has an ‘admin’ scope to send. There is no way for you to add a profile attribute to a user in an Identity Provider that you do not control such as Facebook, Google, or Twitter, or a way to request scopes that the IDP doesn’t provide. If you are using one of these Identity Providers for your users, you will need to keep track of which users are administrators within your application, which of course means having your own user database which kind of defeats the purpose of using OIDC.

If your intention is to grant admin access based on a user being granted an ‘admin’ scope, you will need to be getting the tokens from an Identity Provider that “Knows” whether or not that user is an Admin. This is usually the case for a workforce application that is getting the tokens from a workforce identity provider such as Microsoft Azure or Okta. In this scenario the user has certain attributes such as a job title or membership in a group that will determine if they are an administrator for the application. Access rules in the Authorization server config will determine which scopes the user has access to. For example, all users assigned to the application will have access to default scopes, assigned users who are members of a particular group will have access to default scopes plus the ‘admin’ scope.

You will need to either build or buy an Identity Provider. I work with Okta a lot so that’s what I’m most familiar with, but it is possible to build your own IDP with just the features you need for your application. Now you can control the profiles, or group memberships of users in your Identity provider and configure your own rules for what scopes are authorized for which users. Additionally, to make enrolling, managing, and authenticating users in your IDP easier, you can allow users to enroll and login to your IDP through external IDPs such as Facebook/Twitter/Google.

For the admin UI scenario, if the intention is to do something like display an “Admin” button or other UI elements to users who have admin access but hide it for non-admin users, as you state, you will need to request the ‘admin’ scope from the IDP. You can do this in one of two ways. You can request all scopes including the ‘admin’ scope when the user initially authenticates. If the user is not authorized for the ‘admin’ scope a token will not be returned. If no token is returned, you can then request a token with only default scopes and then display the UI based on the scopes in the token you received.
The other option is to only request a token with default scopes to “log the user in”. Later as you are loading the UI, you can make a subsequent request for a token with the ‘admin’ scope and if you get the token, you can update the UI with the admin elements, otherwise, don’t.

Another approach would be to only request default scopes when a user logs in and not display the admin button right away. You could then make a subsequent request to the authorization server for the authorization scope and if it is returned, populate the “Admin” button.